# Custom configuration for Camunda in a Spring-Boot environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, datasource, camunda

I have 3 classes to inject custom configuration for Camunda as follows. I needed such a configuration because there are other custom DataSources in the environment. The problem is that while configuring the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` I had to configure some values regarding the persistence unit. Finally, in order to configure this bean somehow, I tried my changes by setting packages to scan as `org.camunda`. While this works in my local settings, I get an exception as follows. Note that there is an empty processes.xml file in `resources/META-INF` folder:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'camundaEmfBean' defined in class path resource [eu/nimble/service/bp/config/camunda/CamundaDatasourceConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
        at eu.nimble.service.bp.BusinessProcessApplication.main(BusinessProcessApplication.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:605)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:445)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:426)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:325)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:187)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:602)
        ... 31 common frames omitted
```

The configuration classes are as follows:

```
@Component
public class CamundaDatasourceConfig {
    @Autowired
    private DataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSourceFactory.createDatasource("camunda");
    }

    @Bean(name = "camundaEmfBean")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean camundaEntityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("org.camunda");
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean(name = "camundaTm")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("camundaEmfBean") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory.getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}

public class CamundaDatasourceConfigurationImpl extends AbstractCamundaConfiguration implements CamundaDatasourceConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("camundaTm")
    private PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager;

    @Override
    public void preInit(SpringProcessEngineConfiguration configuration) {
        final DatabaseProperty database = camundaBpmProperties.getDatabase();

        configuration.setTransactionManager(platformTransactionManager);
        configuration.setDataSource(dataSource);
        configuration.setDatabaseType(database.getType());
        configuration.setDatabaseSchemaUpdate(database.getSchemaUpdate());

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(database.getTablePrefix())) {
            configuration.setDatabaseTablePrefix(database.getTablePrefix());
        }
    }
}


@Configuration
public class CamundaConfig {

    @Bean
    public static CamundaDatasourceConfiguration camundaDatasourceConfiguration() {
        return new CamundaDatasourceConfigurationImpl();
    }
}
```

So, how should I set the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` properly? Thanks in advance.